# How to Unmarshall key-less JSON array in Golang correctly?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have JSON data which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "globalTradeID": 64201000,
    "tradeID": 549285,
    "date": "2016-11-11 23:51:58",
    "type": "buy",
    "rate": "10.33999779",
    "amount": "0.02176472",
    "total": "0.22504715"
  },
  {
    "globalTradeID": 64200631,
    "tradeID": 549284,
    "date": "2016-11-11 23:48:39",
    "type": "buy",
    "rate": "10.33999822",
    "amount": "0.18211700",
    "total": "1.88308945"
  }...
]
```

I've tried to unmarshall this JSON by defining a type:

```
type TradeHistoryResponse   []TradeHistoryInfo

type TradeHistoryInfo struct {
    GlobalTradeID   int64   `json:"globalTradeID"`
    TradeID         int64   `json:"tradeID"`
    Date            string  `json:"date"`
    Type            string  `json:"type"`
    Rate            float64 `json:"rate,string"`
    Amount          float64 `json:"amount,string"`
    Total           float64 `json:"total,string"`
}
```

And then pulling the JSON data as so:

```
    //Read response
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("[Poloniex] (doRequest) Failed to parse response for query to %s! (%s)", reqURL, err.Error())
    } 

    //Convert JSON to struct

    var THR TradeHistoryResponse
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &THR)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("[Poloniex] (doRequest) Failed to convert response into JSON for query to %s! (%s)", reqURL, err.Error())
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
(json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type poloniex.TradeHistoryResponse)
```

My best guess why the Unmarshall doesn't work is because the array is key-less?

Would love to have some clarification on the matter on how I might best get this working.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the array is key-less", or what the problem is. Your example code works: https://play.golang.org/p/zbybX0tnRB

Comment: @nik-kunkel your example code works fine, take a look https://play.golang.org/p/743MBHL3Y4. My best guss is that your body is not right. probably what you are reading from body is not that data.

Comment: @JimB and Nik are right,  maybe you should try writing to stdout/file the body you're retrieving and check if all the elements of the array are consistent with the type you're trying to decode into.

Comment: I wrote a modification of your code for better understanding: https://play.golang.org/p/aoqjYyjuXT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't think unmarhsalling an array in a JSON like you intended actually works but to the props of encoding/json it does. Example code:
package main

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

var mjs string = "[" +
    "{" +
    `"globalTradeID": 64201000,
                          "tradeID": 549285,
                          "date": "2016-11-11 23:51:58",
                          "type": "buy",
                          "rate": "10.33999779",
                          "amount": "0.02176472",
                          "total": "0.22504715"
                        },
                        {
                          "globalTradeID": 64200631,
                          "tradeID": 549284,
                          "date": "2016-11-11 23:48:39",
                          "type": "buy",
                          "rate": "10.33999822",
                          "amount": "0.18211700",
                          "total": "1.88308945"
                        }
                        ]`

type TradeHistoryResponse []TradeHistoryInfo

type TradeHistoryInfo struct {
    GlobalTradeID int64   `json:"globalTradeID"`
    TradeID       int64   `json:"tradeID"`
    Date          string  `json:"date"`
    Type          string  `json:"type"`
    Rate          float64 `json:"rate,string"`
    Amount        float64 `json:"amount,string"`
    Total         float64 `json:"total,string"`
}

func main() {

    //Convert JSON to struct

    var THR TradeHistoryResponse
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(mjs), &THR)
    if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    }
  for _, v := range THR {
    fmt.Printf("%+v", v)
    fmt.Printf("\n")
  }
}
```

This prints out all the values as expected. So it doesn't have a problem converting the json values to float/int either (which would have been my second guess).

Are you sure you aren't modifying the Body in any way ? And that the example you give cover all edge cases ?

Could you add:

```
fmt.Println(string(body))
```

to the second error block and log the error it give here.

Also what version of go are you using ? I wouldn't exclude the possibility of encoding/json to have changed between versions. In the end, if this is indeed the case the easy fix would be taking your response as a string, removing all whitespaces and splitting at "}'{" as in:

```
fmtBody := strings.Replace(string(body), "\n", "", -1)
fmtBody = strings.Replace(string(fmtBody), "\w", "", -1)
fmtBody = strings.Replace(string(fmtBody), "[", "", -1)
fmtBody = strings.Replace(string(fmtBody), "]", "", -1)
var goArrOfYourJsonsObj []String = strings.Split(fmtBody, "},{")
for k, _ := range goArrOfYourJsonsObj {
  goArrOfYourJsonsObj[k] += "}"
}
```

And now you have your JSON objects neatly separated into a go array of types String which, can be used in Unmarshall as []byte(val).

Comment: You are correct with your theory the body didn't contain the correct data. I had implemented a method to catch the server returning errors, but it doesn't seem to be working. After further review it seems the server was returning an error because the URL parameters weren't being encoded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**TradeHistoryResponse** is a type no a variable, you have to create a var of type TradeHistoryResponse, like this:

```
var th TradeHistoryResponse

//Convert JSON to struct
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &th)
// ...

fmt.Printf("%+v\n", th)
```

Comment: This was actually a mistake I made when creating this post, to minimize the amount of code I had to post. In the Unmarshall function the second parameter is in fact a variable for TradeHistoryResponse.

Note that I've edited the original post to reflect this.